# Magento 2.4.4 - Vulnerability url issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4, security-patch, vulnerability

We are getting vulnerability url issue in magento 2.
In all magento 2 version we are getting this type of data.
We are getting data on that pages.

```
http://yourdomain.com/customer/section/load/test.aspx
http://yourdomain.com/customer/section/load/bin/
http://yourdomain.com/customer/section/load/CHANGELOG.txt
http://yourdomain.com/customer/section/load/Service/
http://yourdomain.com/customer/section/load/errors/
```

Is there anyone how to solve this ?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: if we hit above Urls, then it prints a lot data into JSON format. need to fix urgently as soon as possible.